# Short story banned for content

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Many years ago I read a collection of stories that had not been published, not because of their quality but because of the challenging themes.

I am trying to remember the name of the story, and its author, that begins with the hero helping some traders that were being robbed. The traders are selling some metal that is vital to everyone, but no one wants to acknowledge it, as the planet where it is mined the inhabitants practice incest. The hero travels to that planet, falls in love with the daughter of the trader, and stays in that planet. Anyway, the story discusses race improvement through inbreeding.

The editor of the book, if I am not mistaken is Isaac Asimov. Or at least, he wrote the introduction to the collection. Many of the authors in that collection were award winning.

Comment: Uh, forgive if I ask the obvious question, but if these weren't published, what did you read them *IN*?

Comment: @Radhil Banned books get de-banned. For example, Thomas Middleton's play *The Revenger's Tragedy* was banned (for valorizing the idea that commoners could kill nobles if I recall correctly) for a few centuries in the UK. Now it's a film. :)

Comment: The uncensored version of Wildes *Portrait of Dorian Gray* was only recently released (well, within the last 5 years or so).

Comment: Banned in which country/countries?

Comment: Can you clarify what the "challenging themes" were? Was it banned for discussing inbreeding? For graphic descriptions of, um, "breeding"?

Answer (score 27):

Sounds like an anthology called *Dangerous Visions*, collected by Harlan Ellison. The story you mention is called "If All Men Were Brothers, Would You Let One Marry Your Sister?" by Theodore Sturgeon. See [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_All_Men_Were_Brothers,_Would_You_Let_One_Marry_Your_Sister%3F) on this story.

> It is about an Earthman who comes to the planet Vexvelt, shunned by the rest of colonized universe for unknown reasons. He finds it a utopian paradise, but then discovers to his shock and horror that incest is actively encouraged there. When it is shown that the reason that the planet is a paradise is because of this encouragement of incest (or, rather, the non-suppression of sexual instincts and urges including incest), then questions are raised of the reader as to how we face "unpleasant" issues.

I haven't heard anything about any of the material in Dangerous Visions being banned.

As one of the comments points out (and see its [ISFDB entry](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41293)), "If All Men Were Brothers . . ." has been anthologized in other collections, some of them edited by Isaac Asimov. But I think the collection the asker is referring to is most likely *Dangerous Visions*, because Isaac Asimov did write the intro to *DV*, and also because the asker remembers the collection as being transgressive and having "challenging themes," which fits the theme of *DV*.

Comment: The short story you IDed here was included in plenty of other [anthologies and collections](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41293)

Comment: This fits and Asimov did write the intro. to DV.

Comment: Good points in the above comments. I added a note to my answer about those.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and get the Dangerous visions. I think the person that answered it got it right. I read the anthology but did not rememeber the name.

Comment: It's also possible that you are conflating Dangerous Visions with The Last Dangerous Visions. The story you refer to was indeed published, but Harlan Ellison (for reasons still unknown) wound up sitting on submissions for LDV, and the book was never published, although 32 of the stories were eventually published elsewhere, and apparently part of it was published. But Ellison's failure was fairly famous among SF circles and may have influenced your recollection.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Heh. Was there a great deal of truth to the rumour that TLDV was never published because it just wasn't any good? While DV was unmatched, the ADV was really not, because all the good authors had already been harvested, and it was filled with creative writing exercises from students on SF writing courses. One wonders whether TLDV had similar problems.

Comment: @PrimeMover - I'm not privy to that information. But it is true that DV got its cachet by being a transgressive groundbreaker - and the field moved on VERY quickly after DV broke the ice. Reading or reading DV nowadays is to wonder just exactly what the fuss was all about. And Harlan Ellison had many virtues, including compulsive honesty (read: no filters), but not exactly adhering to other people's versions of reality. So anything he said on the subject is not to be trusted.